# .Net 4.8 Winforms Application | SQLite-PCL | Exception Info: System.TypeInitializationException | Why?

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, sqlite-net

I'm using the sqlite-net-pcl nuget package (version 1.8.116) in a .Net framework 4.8 Winforms Application. It seems to have a .NET Standard dependency.

When running from the Visual Studio environment, the SQLite libraries initialize without any problems and the necessary read/write aspects of the libraries work as expected.

However, when deploying to a different folder, the application throws an unhandled exception. My windows event viewer provides the following information.

> `Exception Info: System.Exception    at
> SQLitePCL.NativeLibrary.Load(System.String,
> System.Reflection.Assembly, Int32)    at
> SQLitePCL.Batteries_V2.MakeDynamic(System.String, Int32)    at
> SQLitePCL.Batteries_V2.DoDynamic_cdecl(System.String, Int32)    at
> SQLite.SQLiteConnection..cctor()
>
> Exception Info: System.TypeInitializationException    at
> SQLite.SQLiteConnection..ctor(SQLite.SQLiteConnectionString)    at
> SQLite.SQLiteConnectionPool+Entry..ctor(SQLite.SQLiteConnectionString)
> at
> SQLite.SQLiteConnectionPool.GetConnectionAndTransactionLock(SQLite.SQLiteConnectionString,
> System.Object ByRef)    at
> SQLite.SQLiteAsyncConnection+<>c__DisplayClass33_0`1[[SQLite.CreateTableResult, SQLite-net, Version=1.8.116.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].<WriteAsync>b__0()    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[[SQLite.CreateTableResult, SQLite-net,
> Version=1.8.116.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=null]].InnerInvoke()    at
> System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()

The following SQlite DLL files are in the deployment folder

> SQLite-net.dll
> SQLitePCLRaw.batteries_v2.dll
> SQLitePCLRaw.nativelibrary.dll
> SQLitePCLRaw.provider.dynamic_cdecl.dll
> SQLitePCLRaw.core.dll

How to resolve this unhandled exception?

Answer (score 0):

It seems I missed / was not aware of the additional dependencies (libraries).
You will find a "runtimes" folder in your application bin folder.
Within this you will find a "e_sqlite3.dll" file for each relevant system platform.

This "runtimes" folder needs to be deployed (only with the relevant platform subfolders) to your deployment directory (i.e. "next to" you windows application executable)